# uploading file to server failse witha a log - VFY: unable to resolve static field 44070

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, multipartentity

In my **android** project I'm **uploading a zip file** to a server using **HTTP post request**. In this case I'm using **httpcore** and **httpmime** libraries. I'm using an **AsyncTask** to make the upload. the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask is as below,

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                String serverLoaction = params[0];
                String filePath = params[1];

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverLoaction);

                MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(filePath));
                StringBody stringBody = new StringBody("data", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

                builder.addPart("file", fileBody);
                builder.addPart("name", stringBody);

                httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                return sResponse;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in downloading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
```

the code is **compile** and **run** well. but when **upload task** is carry on it **does not upload** the file and in the **Log** it shows below **massage**.

```
05-03 14:29:00.223 27471-27687/com.x.l D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;.INSTANCE
05-03 14:29:00.223 27471-27687/com.x.l W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 44070 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;
05-03 14:29:00.223 27471-27687/com.x.l D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b
05-03 14:29:00.233 27471-27687/com.x.l D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;.INSTANCE
05-03 14:29:00.233 27471-27687/com.x.l W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 44065 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;
05-03 14:29:00.233 27471-27687/com.x.l D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0015
```

but it doesn't give any **error**. so i spent sum painful time trying to figure it out and i wasn't succeed.

the **dependencies** in my build.gradle file are as below,

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'

}
```

Editted.......
according to a stac answer I edited my code and added following two parts

```
String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
```

and

```
builder.setBoundary(boundary);
```

so now my final code is like this.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            String serverLoaction = params[0];
            String filePath = params[1];

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverLoaction);

            String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            builder.setBoundary(boundary);

            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(filePath));
            StringBody stringBody = new StringBody("data", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            builder.addPart("file", fileBody);
            builder.addPart("name", stringBody);

            httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

            String sResponse = reader.readLine();
            return sResponse;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in downloading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

so now it doesnt show that error I mentioned above. but still its not uploading the file.
 what's the wrong with my code. can someone suggest me possible fix for this issue. Thanks and regards!

Comment: This code works fine. it was some problem with the server. thanks and regards !

Answer (score 0):

I using volley library to upload file. 
 Hope this code can help you.
This is class i using to request to server.

> public class OnPostNewtRequest extends JsonRequest {
>       MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
>       HttpEntity httpentity;
>       private final Response.Listener mListener;
>       private File mFilePart = null;
>       private File mFileVideos = null;
>       private final Map mStringPart;
>
> ```
> public OnPostNewtRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
>                          Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, File file,
>                          File fileVideos, Map<String, String> mStringPart) {
>     super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
>     mListener = listener;
>     mFilePart = file;
>     mFileVideos = fileVideos;
>     this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
>     entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
>     buildMultipartEntity();
> }
>
> public void addStringBody(String param, String value) {
>     mStringPart.put(param, value);
> }
>
> private void buildMultipartEntity() {
>     if (mFileVideos != null)
>         entity.addBinaryBody(Constant.KEY_FILE_VIDEO, mFileVideos, ContentType.create("video/mp4"), mFileVideos.getName());
>     if (mFilePart != null)
>         entity.addBinaryBody(Constant.KEY_FILE, mFilePart, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), mFilePart.getName());
>     for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
>         try {
>             entity.addPart(entry.getKey(), new StringBody(entry.getValue(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
>         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public String getBodyContentType() {
>     return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
> }
>
> @Override
> public byte[] getBody() {
>     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>     try {
>         httpentity = entity.build();
>         httpentity.writeTo(bos);
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
>     }
>     return bos.toByteArray();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
>     try {
>         String jsonString =
>                 new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
>         return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
>                 HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
>     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>         return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
>     } catch (JSONException je) {
>         return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
>     mListener.onResponse(response);
> }
> ```
>
> }

And How to using this request.
1 . First you using

 Map params = new HashMap();
 To add "key" and values to params example : params.put(Constant.KEY_WORD, mTag);.

 Step 2 .

OnPostNewtRequest multipartRequest = new OnPostNewtRequest(Constant.URL_UP_POST, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (mAction != null) {
                    mAction.onError(error);
                }
                dismiss();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

```
        }
    }, linkFileImage, fileVideos, params);

    YourApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

Hope this help you.